# Configure Firebase push messages with Maven Android project

Tags: android, maven, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a way to properly configure Firebase messaging with Maven without using Gradle?

I've added this dependency to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-messaging</artifactId>
    <version>9.0.2</version>
    <type>aar</type>
</dependency>
```

And modified my AndroidManifest.xml by copying configs from AndroidManifest.xml file located in firebase AAR. I didn't find the way to filter them during maven buld using filtering resources or replacer plugin like gradle plugin do.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="<MY_APP_PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="<MY_APP_PACKAGE>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<!-- copied from firebase common module to be able to set <MY_APP_PACKAGE>
     (that is set during compilation with gradle plugin)  --> 
<provider
        android:authorities="<MY_APP_PACKAGE>.firebaseinitprovider"
        android:name="com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:initOrder="99" />
<!-- copied from firebase iid module to be able to set <MY_APP_PACKAGE>
     (that is set during compilation with gradle plugin)  --> 
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        <category android:name="<MY_APP_PACKAGE>" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".service.PushMessageService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
</intent-filter>
</service>
<service android:name=".service.GoogleIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Also, added string resources (that auto set by gradle plugin from config json file)

```
<string name="google_app_id" translatable="false">...</string>
<string name="google_api_key" translatable="false">...</string>
<string name="firebase_database_url" translatable="false">...</string>
<string name="ga_trackingId" translatable="false">...</string>
<string name="gcm_defaultSenderId" translatable="false">...</string>
<string name="google_storage_bucket" translatable="false">...</string>
```

After running the app I had these logs

```
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ Initialized class com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
D/FirebaseApp﹕ com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement is not linked. Skipping initialization.
I/FirebaseInitProvider﹕ FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

The docs says Firebase will request new token automatically but I never receive **onTokenRefresh** callback
Is there anything I missed?

P.S: Please don't suggest using Gradle....

Any help is appreciated...
Thanks

Comment: you must login with firebase

Comment: It looks like the FirebaseApp is initializing, but not pulling in some of its (normally transitive) dependencies. That doesn't have to be a problem. For the `onTokenRefresh()` part: not that this method will only be called *when* the token is refreshed. If you added the code *after* the token was generated, it won't get called. To test if this is the case, log the value of ` FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` somewhere to see if your device/app has a token.

Comment: Cross-post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/PlH-tKo6dL8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your custom implementation is almost correct.
You are missing this:

```
<receiver       
android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
android:exported="false" />
```

BUT.. I have to warn you that the approach of manually modifying the AndroidManifest is **highly discouraged**. Since the manifest is automatically configured by Gradle we consider it as an **internal implementation details** and not officially supported API.

Long story short: the manifest configuration could change at any release, and your app would break if you don't update your manifest accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for help. It worked! But I don't use Gradle, this is only Maven implementation

Answer (score 0):

The issue resolved, thanks Diego

I just wanted to add some additional configs to AndroidManifest.xml for someone who will perform same issue

(all copied from firebase AndroidManifest.xml

```
<!-- Internal (not exported) receiver used by the app to start its own exported services
     without risk of being spoofed. -->
<receiver
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver"
        android:exported="false" />

<!-- FirebaseInstanceIdService performs security checks at runtime,
     no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->
<service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>

<!-- FirebaseMessagingService performs security checks at runtime,
     no need for explicit permissions despite exported="true" -->
<service
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService"
        android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```