# Android Firebase dependencies in Maven

Tags: android, maven, firebase, dependencies, pom.xml

My Android project is using Maven and I have no option available to move to gradle. I have integrated Firebase messaging in a sample gradle project, but now I want to implement it in my maven based project. But I am unable to fix the dependencies.

The dependencies that I declared in sample project gradle are

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:9.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
```

For maven dependencies I tried to find these on maven but was not able to get them over there, although I manage to find few other dependencies that look relevant to them, but they not what I am looking for.

com.firebase
        firebase-client-android
        2.5.2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.firebase</groupId>
    <artifactId>firebase-token-generator</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38475560/configure-firebase-push-messages-with-maven-android-project) post mentions that he was able to get dependecy working on maven, I tried it out but was still giving error stating "aar" not found.

That makes me wonder is maven dependency is possible for Firebase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All firebase module's **.aar** and **.pom** files are available inside Android SDK, exact path to be

> /Users/{username}/Library/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/firebase/

Once there you can retrieve the **.aar** file of whatever module you looking for and change the file type to **.zip**. Extract the content of **.zip** file and it will give you **classes.jar** file. You can rename this **.jar** file by the module name and use it in your project as you use any other jar file, no need to add maven dependency.